# Затыки при построении маршрута с помощью ymaps.route

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При построении маршрута через некоторые точки (вероятно - находящиеся на некой закрытой территории) маршрутизатор "затыкается" на этих точках и далее маршрут не строит. Пример кода:

```js
function init() {
  var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    // Описание опорных точек мультимаршрута.
    referencePoints: [
      [55.861352, 37.545552],
      [55.730086, 37.589239], // Комсомольский проспект, 13
      [55.729914, 37.397207],
    ],
    params: {
      results: 2
    }
  }, {
    boundsAutoApply: true
  });

  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.750625, 37.626],
    zoom: 7
  }, {
    buttonMaxWidth: 300
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Здесь маршрут построится только до точки B. При этом, если слегка "сдвинуть" координаты точки например на [55.730086, 37.589039], то маршрут построится нормально - через все точки.

Координаты получаются через отдельное приложение по адресу с помощью Яндекс.Геокодера и как-то корректировать их налету нет возможности.

Вопрос - есть ли возможность либо строить маршрут "рядом" с такими закрытыми территориями, либо при получении координат получать координаты точки ближайшего возможного подъезда.

Comment: и правда странно, до точки C можно доехать по дорогам: https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CBe2bRDsTA
будем разбираться, почему так

Comment: Еще пример "мертвой" точки: [55.715408, 37.692258] - ул.Угрешская, 26

Comment: этот пример тоже забрала

Comment: Починили, проверяйте

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже сталкивался с подобным - пример:

```js
ymaps.ready(function(){
 var clients = [
  [44.945849, 54.072319],
  [44.938231, 54.075309],
  [44.948723, 54.056429],
  [44.956952, 54.077633],
  [36.71596, 56.672646],
  [36.771413, 56.685423],
  [36.766095, 56.691316],
  [36.791131, 56.701383],
  [36.770919, 56.718211]
 ];
 var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
  center: [37.61691485505143, 55.7517318022522],
  zoom: 10
 });
 for(var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
  var tmp_point = new ymaps.Placemark(clients[i], {
   balloonContent: 'Точка ' + (i + 1),
   iconContent: 'Точка ' + (i + 1)
  }, {
   preset: 'islands#blueStretchyIcon'
  });
  tmp_point.coordinates = clients[i];
  myMap.geoObjects.add(tmp_point);
 }
 myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
 var route = null;
 var current_point_coords = [];
 myMap.geoObjects.events.add('contextmenu', function(e){
  var current_point = e.get('target');
  current_point_coords.push(current_point.coordinates);
  if(route){
   myMap.geoObjects.remove(route);
  }
  route = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: current_point_coords,
    params: {
     results: 1, // ограничение на максимальное количество маршрутов, возвращаемое маршрутизатором
     avoidTrafficJams: true
    }
   }, {}
  );
  myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
 });
});
```

```css
html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #000000;
 clear: both;
}

#map {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&coordorder=longlat"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

На карте две группы точек, маршрут строится последовательным добавлением точек путем клика по точке правой кнопкой мыши. Как видно из примера, маршрут также не строится после точек 3 и 8. И таких точек в последнее время стало очень много.

Вот что ответили в поддержке Яндекса:

> В точке 3 маршрут попадает в тупик и маршрутизатор не может
>   развернуться на однореберной дороге. Чтобы маршрут построился, нужно
>   передвинуть метку ближе к дороге https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CBeH6HHL9A -
>   в настоящий момент это единственный вариант.
>
> Мы уже в курсе данной проблемы, наши специалисты занимаются ее
>   решением. К сожалению, задача трудоемкая и может потребовать
>   достаточно много времени. Приносим свои извинения за доставленные
>   неудобства!

Comment: Спасибо, опытным путем пришел к тому же "решению", хотя в моем случае это ставит под вопрос возможность автоматизации бизнес-процесса. Странно, но стали замечать такое буквально пару дней назад. До этого не встречали таких проблем, возможно просто везло. Скажите - как давно получен этот ответ из поддержки Яндекса?

Comment: Ответ от Яндекса был получен ровно неделю назад. Раньше таких случаев было крайне мало, но в последний месяц подобные случаи участились. Для нас двигать точки вообще не вариант, т.к. точка ставится на карту через сервис геокодирования - какие координаты Яндекс определил, там точка и поставилась. Обиднее еще и то, что мы используем платную версию API, и нет конкретных сроков устранения данной ошибки.

Comment: Починили, проверяйте

Comment: Проверил, вроде работает. У себя настроил перетаскиваемые метки, и если были затыки, передвигал немного метки. А в чем была проблема?